# How to retrieve data from csv file and put in respective textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have used 3 textboxes to extract filename, file extension and path from a particular folder respectively in textbox2, textbox3 & textbox1. This data get stored in a `.csv` file.

**Problem 1:** I want to extract this data in their respective textbox from reading this `.csv` file, when I press button6.

**Problem 2:** how can I show the relative path rather than showing full path? (I think substring method be used for this problem but how :|)

For example:

Showing `Chrome\Application\38.0.2125.104\fileA.exe`
     OR `Update\1.3.24.15\fileB.exe`

rather than showing

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\38.0.2125.104\fileA.exe
```

OR

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\1.3.24.15\fileB.exe
```

XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="FileFinder.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="FileCopier"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Width="1366" Height="758">
<Grid Background="LavenderBlush">

    <Label Height="40" Margin="240,0,234,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="28" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Broadway">Welcome To</Label>

    <Label Height="55" Margin="194,35,194,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="45" Foreground="Chocolate" FontFamily="Colonna MT">FILE FINDER</Label>

    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" AutoWordSelection="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="475.857,211,20,21" Name="textbox1" Background="LavenderBlush" Opacity="0.7" ScrollBar.Scroll="Scroll" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBox>

    <Button ToolTip="Click to search exe files" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="366,96,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" Background="LavenderBlush" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkSeaGreen" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" Click="button1_Click" FontFamily="Broadway" Cursor="Hand">.exe</Button>

    <Button ToolTip="Click to search dll files" Margin="602,96,0,0" Name="button2" Background="LavenderBlush" BorderBrush="DarkSeaGreen" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Click="button2_Click" FontFamily="Broadway" Cursor="Hand" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="123">.dll</Button>

    <Button Background="LavenderBlush" BorderBrush="DarkSeaGreen" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,96,383,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" Click="button3_Click" FontFamily="Broadway">All</Button>

    <Label FontFamily="Broadway" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Height="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="12,165,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="230.069" Opacity="0.6">Filename</Label>

    <Label FontFamily="Broadway" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Height="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,165,234,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0.6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="86.627">Path</Label>

    <Button  Name="button4" Click="button4_Click" Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,173,175,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Background="LavenderBlush" ToolTip="PageUp">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="C:\Users\Vipul.Sharma\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\FileFinder\FileFinder\PageUp.png"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Button Name="button5" Click="button5_Click" Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,173,140,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Background="LavenderBlush" ToolTip="PageUp">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="C:\Users\Vipul.Sharma\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\FileFinder\FileFinder\PageDown.png" Opacity="0.7"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" AutoWordSelection="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="20,211,0,21" Name="textbox2" Background="LavenderBlush" Opacity="0.7" ScrollBar.Scroll="Scroll" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="345.818"></TextBox>
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" AutoWordSelection="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="371.54,211,0,21" Name="textBox3" Width="106.46" Background="LavenderBlush" Opacity="0.7" ScrollBar.Scroll="Scroll" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBox>
    <Label FontFamily="Broadway" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="305.806,165.764,0,0" Name="label5" Opacity="0.6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230.069">Extension</Label>
    <Button Background="LavenderBlush" BorderBrush="DarkSeaGreen" FontFamily="Broadway" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,95.743,143,0" Name="button6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" Click="button6_Click">GetFile</Button>
</Grid>
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace FileFinder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<String> files = new List<String>();
            String[] extensions = new[] { "*.exe" };

            foreach (String extension in extensions)
            {
                String[] lol = Directory.GetFiles(@"mypath", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (String file in lol)
                files.Add(file);
            }
            textbox1.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textbox1.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
            textbox2.Text += Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i]) + "\n";
            textBox3.Text += Path.GetExtension(files[i]) + "\n";
            textbox1.Text += files[i] + "\n";
            }

           List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
           for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
           {
                lstResult.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i]) + "," + Path.GetExtension(files[i])+"," + Path.GetFullPath(files[i]));
           }
           File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\BigB.csv", lstResult.ToArray());

       }
    private void Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == textbox1 || sender == textBox3)
        {
            textbox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
            textBox3.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
        }
        else
        {
            textbox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
            textBox3.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
        }
    }

   //WHAT I HAVE SEEN AND TRIED
   private void button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadCSV("BigB.csv");
        textbox2.Text += name;
        textbox1.Text += extension;
        textBox3.Text += path;
    }

    public class InOrder
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

        public string extension { get; set; }

        public string path { get; set; }

        public InOrder(string n, string ext, string p)
        {
            name = n;
            extension = ext;
            path = p;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<InOrder> ReadCSV(string fileName)
    {
        // We change file extension here to make sure it's a .csv file.
        string[] collectBack = File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(@"C:\BigB.csv", ".csv"));

        // lines.Select allows me to project each line as a InOrder. 
        // This will give me an IEnumerable<InOrder> back.
        return 
        {
            string[] data = collectBack.Split(';');
            // We return a person with the data in order.
            return new InOrder(data[0], data[1], (data[2]));  
        });          
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice name for you String[] , lol :P

Answer (score 0):

You're working with XAML, so you should bind to your control instead of doing `textbox2.Text = "something"`. Once you do that you don't need any of those "Name" properties in your XAML code. If you do need to name anything, use proper, descriptive names: `textbox2` doesn't tell me anything.

Why do `foreach (String extension in extensions)` when you never use `extension`?

IMHO most of the code in `button1_Click` should be moved to separate classes: one class to retrieve the list of files, another to write the list of files to a file.

Why do for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++) when you can simply do `foreach (var file in files)`?

Why store the result of `Directory.GetFiles` in the (badly named) variable `lol` when you could simply use the AddRange method of `files`?

If you want to show `Update\1.3.24.15\fileB.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\1.3.24.15\fileB.exe`, simply use the [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method to replace `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\` with `string.Empty`. You should have no trouble finding C# code to read the contents of a file.

To me `InOrder` is a bad class name, since it doesn't tell me what it contains. `FileData` or `FileProperties` makes more sense. You should use this class more often, e.g. instead of getting `List<String> files`, parse the result Directory.GetFiles immediately and convert it to a `List<FileData>` and iterate over these when assigning `textbox2`, `textBox3`, `textbox1`,...

Why is there a call to `System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension`?

`ReadCSV` returns an `IEnumerable<InOrder>`, but you don't loop through the results.

Why require a `filename` to be passed to `ReadCSV` when you don't use it?

`public string name { get; set; }` violates Microsoft's naming rules: Properties should be PascalCase.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. Henceforth, I will make sure I give variables a reasonable name and will definitely improve my code as you have suggested.
I have used System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension to make sure that the file is in .csv format.

Answer (score 0):

Why use those intermediate steps?

```
List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
foreach (String lol in Directory.GetFiles(@"mypath", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);s)
{    
    lstResult.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lol) + "," + Path.GetExtension(lol)+"," + Path.GetFullPath(lol);

    sb1.AppendLine(lol);
    sb2.AppendLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lol));
    sb3.AppendLine(Path.GetExtension(lol));
}

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\BigB.csv", lstResult.ToArray());

textbox1.Text = sb1.ToString();
textbox2.Text = sb2.ToString();
textbox3.Text = sb3.ToString();
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks Mr. Blam for a much cleaner code.